# FragmentedTabHost cannot change unselected background

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabhost

I have been trying to edit a FragmentedTabHost's background colors to mess around with it a bit and I am quite clueless as to why I can changed the "unselected" state but not the "selected" state.

So what I have is a main drawable called "tabs" and inside I have references to two others "tab_selected" and "tab_unselected". I applied this background pretty much everywhere I could find to see if it worked but I got to the point where I think the best place to put it is in the TabWidget tag.

The selected state remains with the grayish color of the normal tab but the other one actually changes.

I don't know if I should be changing code elsewhere, as I already changed in the code it self by saying:

```
mTabHost.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabs);
```

And still no progress...

Below is the code:

tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
</selector>
```

tab_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#7fff00" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#7fff00" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#7fff00"
            android:endColor="#7fff00"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

tab_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#86B4CF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#86B4CF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#86B4CF"
            android:endColor="#6792AB"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And finally the FragmentedHost:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/global_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        style="@style/header"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/tabs"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did u checked `setOnTabChangedListener` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your answers although I decided to go another way around.

As instead of using FragmentedTabHost I decided to use ActionBar Tab because it is the most recomended.

To do this I created this class:

```
public class ActionBarTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public Fragment fragment;

public ActionBarTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    //do what you want when tab is reselected, I do nothing
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}
}
```

Changed my main class (the one holding all the tabs):

```
public class EntryDetails extends ActionBarActivity {

private Entry entry;

//private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private TextView tv_date;
private ActionBar ab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry_details);

    ab = getSupportActionBar();

    ab.setTitle("Ecz :: Entry Details");
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    entry = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("e");

    /* TAB ITCHES */

    Bundle i = new Bundle();
    i.putParcelableArrayList("i", ArrayListHelper.OrderItchesByTime(entry.getItches()));

    Fragment f = new TabItches();
    f.setArguments(i);

    ActionBar.Tab tab = ab.newTab().setText("Itches").setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener(f)).setTag(i);
    ab.addTab(tab);

    /* TAB TREATMENTS */

    i = new Bundle();
    i.putParcelableArrayList("t", ArrayListHelper.OrderTreatmentsByTime(entry.getTreatments()));

    f = new TabTreatments();
    f.setArguments(i);

    tab = ab.newTab().setText("Treatments").setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener(f)).setTag(i);
    ab.addTab(tab);

    tv_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

    tv_date.setText(entry.getDate());
}

}
```

Then I changed my XML in my EntryDetails.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/global_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        style="@style/header"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So now I only have the linearlayout and no more tabhost.

To give you more insight I place below the code to my TabItches:

```
public class TabItches extends ListFragment{

private ArrayList<Itch> itches;
public ListAdapter itchesAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout_itches, container, false);

    this.setRetainInstance(true);

    itches = this.getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("i");

    itchesAdapter = new ItchAdapter(getActivity(), itches);

    setListAdapter(itchesAdapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

To edit the appearance of my tabs now I had to do more things!
This code belongs in "@style"

```
<style name="Appy" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppyActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/AppyActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/AppyActionBarTab</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="AppyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/AppyBlue</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/AppyBlue</item>
</style>

<style name="AppyActionBarTab"    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_background</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_background</item>

    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Only take into account "AppyActionBarTab" code bits please!

actionbar_tab_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/AppyDeeperBlue"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_tab_background_selected"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_tab_background_selected_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

actionbar_tab_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@color/AppyBlue" android:width="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/AppyDeeperBlue"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

actionbar_tab_selected_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="#B8D0DE" android:width="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/AppyDeeperBlue"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I based my self on posts here all throughout StackOverFlow if I manage to find them again I will reference them.

Right now I am struggling with changing the divider's color in API 10 and I cannot seem to get around it! :D

I hope the answer is complete enough, if any problem just write and I will try to answer accordingly!!

*EDIT*
Fixed my problem with divider's color. What you need to do is change the divider's drawable.

action_tab_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/AppyBlue" />
<stroke android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@color/AppyBlue"/>
</shape>
```

and now you need to apply this to the style

```
<style name="Appy" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppyActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/AppyActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/AppyActionBarTab</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_tab_divider</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_tab_divider</item>
</style>
```

Notice that we are overwriting in the "parent" style, not inside either of the two above!

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `setOnTabChangedListener`. i hope this will help you

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                setTabColor(mTabHost);
            }
        });
```

`setTabColor(mTabHost)` **Function** :

```
    public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#434a54")); // unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab())
            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#22262c")); // selected
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I will not be able to get around it right now to see if it would work or not. As an alternative I wrote an answer as well, but its a work around!